# Analysis of Variance with non equal variance

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, variance, poisson-distribution, biostatistics

For my mini project I have to compare the number of different species observed accross 9 different locations. Every location has 3 replicates, so in total there are only 27 observations.

I wanted to do an ANOVA and I thought I need to use glm of the poisson family because this concerns count data. However, the variances are unequal (Bartlett test). I've tried using oneway.test, but I'm getting: F = NaN, num df = 8, denom df = NaN, p-value = NA. I have read somewhere that this can be due to there being no variance in a certain level. (All 3 replicates in 1 location have the same count of species).

Is there anything I can do for this case? Can I still use a test that shows whether or not there is a significant analysis between these locations and maybe even a multiple comparisons that shows which locations differ from each other?

I also calculated a diversity index for each replicate in each location that I also want to analyze.  I figured I wouldnt need to use glm from the poisson family, but just the normal lm(). However, this time there is both unequal variance and non homogeneity! I tried log transforming the data, but it's still non normal and unequal variance.. I am lost on what I can do here.

I do not have much experience in statistics and I am working in R. Any help woud be very much appreciated!!!

Comment: I doubt that number of species seen at a location has a Poisson distribution ... Maybe you can share your data (preferably in a form suitable for direct input into R), or at least show some plots or tables?

Comment: What does the unequal variance have to do with a Poisson GLM?

Comment: It's hard to provide help on this without seeing the actual data (or something similar if you can't show the actual data) and without knowing the specific hypothesis you want to test. You talk about "the number of different species" at first, which just sounds like how many different _species_ you observed, but a diversity index typically also includes the _number_ of cases of _each_ of the species in the calculation. Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.